# WPF Visual Basic Nested DataGrid in TemplateColumn

Tags: vba, wpfdatagrid

I am a newcomer to this forum and also relative newcomer in programming.

Nevertheless I went to a personal music player using WPF/Visual Basic have dared and fought very( !) Long on the following issue:

Equivalent to the media player I would like for the respective artist in a list to the right of the respective title album art and other info view.

For this I have a DataGrid (Master) for the respective albums of the interprets - as far as easily; to now display album art from the respective song details right now, I need the possibility, in a TemplateColumn ** ** another DataGrid (child) to "Nesting", but what I regarding Petrol Ofisi

A solution that comes very close to that in this Link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36909161-3afc-4fcc-af0a-da377a65e421/wpf-grid-column-databinding-to-comple is present, but only to a limited extent for me understandable, since

- Programming in C# is,
- the data binding via defined Collection-Klassen and last, but not least
- the solution uses a converter, an issue with its implementation was really hard for me do.

  ```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,-7.6,-2.4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1344.8" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="790">
  <DataGrid x:Name="AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="413.6" Margin="-7.2,362.4,0,0" Width="1345.2" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#FF2F3699" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" MaxHeight="800" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFFFC20E" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
      <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle>
              <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock x:Name="GroupHeaderAlbum" Background="#FFFFC20E" Foreground="#FF2F3699" FontSize="40.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
          </GroupStyle>
      </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="AlbumCover" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" SortMemberPath="Album.SortName" Header="AlbumCover" SortDirection="Ascending">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <Grid x:Name="GridAlbumCover" Background="#FFFFC20E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Height="190">
                          <Image Source="{Binding AlbumcoverBildDatei}" Stretch="Fill" Height="180" Width="180" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                      </Grid>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AlbumID" Binding="{Binding AlbumID}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="AlbumID" Visibility="Hidden" d:IsHidden="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Album" Binding="{Binding Album}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Album" Visibility="Hidden" d:IsHidden="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Orchestra" Binding="{Binding Orchestra}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Orchestra" Visibility="Hidden" d:IsHidden="True"/>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="AlbenInterpretenAlbenSongs" Header="" Visibility="Visible" CanUserReorder="False">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <DataGrid x:Name="AlbenInterpretenAlbenSongsDG" **Binding=??????** VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="0,0,-169.6,-3.6" Width="1324.4" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#FF2F3699" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" MaxHeight="800" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFFFC20E" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFFFC20E" HeadersVisibility="None">
                          <DataGrid.RowBackground>
                              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFBCBEDC" Offset="0.085"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                              </LinearGradientBrush>
                          </DataGrid.RowBackground>
                          <DataGrid.BorderBrush>
                              <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF688CAF" Opacity="0"/>
                          </DataGrid.BorderBrush>
                          <DataGrid.Columns>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OrchestraDG" Binding="{Binding Orchestra}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Orchestra}" FontSize="37.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Album-Interpret" SortMemberPath="Orchestra" CanUserSort="True" Visibility="Hidden" Width="370"/>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AlbumIDDG" Binding="{Binding AlbumID}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding AlbumID}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="AlbumID" SortMemberPath="AlbumID" CanUserSort="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AlbumNameDG" Binding="{Binding Album}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Album}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Album" SortMemberPath="Alben.SortName" CanUserSort="True" Width="190" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NrDG" Binding="{Binding Track}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Track}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Nr." SortMemberPath="Track" CanUserSort="True" Width="50">
                                  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                      <Style>
                                          <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                      </Style>
                                  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                              </DataGridTextColumn>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SongTitelDG" Binding="{Binding Title}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Title}" FontSize="41.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Song-Titel" Width="505"/>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="InterpretDG" Binding="{Binding Artist}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Artist}" FontSize="37.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Interpret" Width="380"/>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LängeDG" Binding="{Binding Length, StringFormat=m:ss}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Length}" FontSize="37.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Länge" Width="90">
                                  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                      <Style>
                                          <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                      </Style>
                                  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                              </DataGridTextColumn>
                              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JahrDG" Binding="{Binding SongsAlben/ErscheinungsJahr}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ErscheinungsJahr}" FontSize="37.333" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" Header="Jahr" Width="100">
                                  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                      <Style>
                                          <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                      </Style>
                                  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                              </DataGridTextColumn>
                          </DataGrid.Columns>
                      </DataGrid>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>

  Public Function GetAbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongs() As DataTable
  Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongs ORDER BY AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlben.AlbenInterpreten.SortName, AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlben.Alben.SortName, Songs.Track", Application.con)
  Dim AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongsDataSet As New DataSet()
  adapter.Fill(AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongsDataSet, "AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongs")
  Return AbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongsDataSet.Tables(0)
  Application.con.Close()
  ```

  End Function

  ```
  Private Sub PageAlbumInterpret_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
  ```

`Dim AlbenInterpretenAlbenDS As DataSet
AlbenInterpretenAlbenDS = GetAbfrageAlbenInterpretenAlbenSongs()
' Set the DataContext of AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG to DataTable
AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG.DataContext = AlbenInterpretenAlbenDS.Tables(0)
AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG.ItemsSource = AlbenInterpretenAlbenDS.Tables(0).DefaultView`

```
End Sub

    Private Sub Artist_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs)

    'ALBEN UND SONGS
    Dim cvAlben As BindingListCollectionView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG.ItemsSource),BindingListCollectionView)
    CVAlben.CustomFilter = "Orchestra = '" & Artist.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "' Or Orchestra Like '" & Artist.Text.Replace("'", "''") & ";%' Or Orchestra Like '%; " & Artist.Text.Replace("'", "''") & ";%' Or Orchestra Like '%; " & Artist.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'"
    Dim ArtistString As String
    ArtistString = Me.Artist.Text
    Dim DRV As DataRowView
    For Each DRV In AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG.Items
        If ArtistString = DRV("Orchestra") Then
            AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG.GroupStyle.Item(0) = CType(PageAlbumInterpret.FindResource("GroupHeaderStyleAlbum"), GroupStyle)
        Else
           AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG.GroupStyle.Item(0) = CType(PageAlbumInterpret.FindResource("GroupHeaderStyleOrchestraAlbum"), GroupStyle)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    CVAlben.MoveCurrentToFirst
    Dim border As Decorator = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(AlbenInterpretenAlbenDG, 0)
    If border IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim scrollViewer As ScrollViewer = border.Child
        scrollViewer.ScrollToTop()
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you Yve; I noticed my failure too late - sorry!